# Boost ASIO book

Tags: c++, books

I'm an advanced C++ programmer. I've been using Boost ASIO for a while now (a few years, every now and then), but I'd like to learn everything there's to learn about ASIO; i.e., all the tricks and quirks possible with `io_service` and sockets.

I'm looking for a book that's in the level of [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933988770) in multithreading. What I like about this book is that it starts from the very beginning with very basic information, and then advances to a very advanced level that it covers literally everything.

Is there a Boost ASIO book that does the same, or as close as possible?

The books I found are these: [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1782163263), [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1785283073) and [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1783986549). The reviews are quite confusing.

Comment: Please read this question which was posted on Software Recommendations Meta:[Resources for training about software?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2671/resources-for-training-about-software)

Comment: @karel Oh, damn! This is off-topic here. Would you recommend a stackexchange place to ask this question?